# Templated copy-constructor fails with specific templated type

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, copy-constructor

As some of my code required implicit conversion between matrices of different types (e.g. `Matrix<int>` to `Matrix<double>`), I defined a templated copy constructor `Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix<U> const&)` instead of the standard `Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix<T> const&)`:

```
template <typename T> class Matrix {
public:
    // ...
    template <typename U> Matrix(Matrix<U> const&);
    // ...
private
    unsigned int m_rows, m_cols;
    T *m_data;
    // ...
};
```

With an appropriate typecast added to the copy-constructor, this method flawlessly converted between matrices of different types. Surprisingly, it fails with a malloc error in the very situation where a simple copy-constructor would function: where `U == T`. Sure enough, overloading the copy-constructor with the default `Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix<T> const&)` signature solves the problem.

This is a poor solution, as it results in the wholesale duplication of the copy-constructor code (Literally an unchanged copy-and-paste). More importantly, I do not understand why there is a double-free `malloc` error without the duplicate code. Furthermore, why is the extremely verbose `template <typename T> template <typename U>` syntax required here as opposed to the standard, and much more succinct, `template <typename T, typename U>`?

Full source of the templated method, compiled using G++ v4.0.1 on Mac OS 10.5.

```
template <typename T> template <typename U> Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix<U> const& obj) {
    m_rows = obj.GetNumRows();
    m_cols = obj.GetNumCols();
    m_data = new T[m_rows * m_cols];

    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < m_rows; ++r) {
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < m_cols; ++c) {
            m_data[m_rows * r + c] = static_cast<T>(obj(r, c));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It fails because a template doesn't suppress the implicit declaration of a copy constructor. It will serve as a simple converting constructor, which can be used to copy an object when overload resolution selects it.

Now, you probably copied your matrix somewhere, which would use the implicitly defined copy constructor which does a flat copy. Then, the copied matrix and the copy would both in their destructor delete the same pointer.

> Furthermore, why is the extremely verbose `template <typename T> template <typename U>` syntax required

Because there are two templates involved: The Matrix, which is a class template, and the converting constructor template. Each template deserves its own template clause with its own parameters.

You should get rid of the `<T>` in your first line, by the way. Such a thing does not appear when defining a template.

> This is a poor solution, as it results in the wholesale duplication of the copy-constructor code

You can define a member function template, which will do the work, and delegate from both the converting constructor and the copy constructor. That way, the code is not duplicated.

---

Richard made a good point in the comments which made me amend my answer. If the candidate function generated from the template is a better match than the implicitly declared copy constructor, then the template "wins", and it will be called. Here are two common examples:

```
struct A {
  template<typename T>
  A(T&) { std::cout << "A(T&)"; }
  A() { }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  A b(a); // template wins:
          //   A<A>(A&)  -- specialization
          //   A(A const&); -- implicit copy constructor
          // (prefer less qualification)

  A const a1;
  A b1(a1); // implicit copy constructor wins: 
            //   A(A const&) -- specialization
            //   A(A const&) -- implicit copy constructor
            // (prefer non-template)
}
```

A copy constructor can have a non-const reference parameter too, if any of its members has

```
struct B { B(B&) { } B() { } };
struct A {
  template<typename T>
  A(T&) { std::cout << "A(T&)"; }
  A() { }
  B b;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  A b(a); // implicit copy constructor wins:
          //   A<A>(A&)  -- specialization
          //   A(A&); -- implicit copy constructor
          // (prefer non-template)

  A const a1;
  A b1(a1); // template wins: 
            //   A(A const&) -- specialization
            // (implicit copy constructor not viable)
}
```

Comment: Your explanation for the malloc error sounds spot on. Is there a specific reason for why compilers can't use a template member function as a copy-constructor? Thanks for the information and for the advice to avoid code duplication.

Comment: If you have that template, it's not a function yet. Only usage of it with some template argument generates a (member-) function out of it (called a specialization). This is also the reason why member templates can't be virtual: You don't know in advance what functions are generated from it.

Comment: That makes a great deal of sense - this does not work for the very reason that one needs to either forward declare template parameters or include the full source of the implementation. Thanks again.

Comment: "..a template can never serve as a copy constructor.":  This is a bit misleading.  The correct statement is:  "a template copy constructor does not suppress the compiler generated implicit copy constructor".  The reason that this is important is that if you provide a non template copy constructor that has a worse conversion than the template constructor, then the template constructor will be selected.  For example: "Matric(Matric const volarile & m)".  The usual case is that the implicitly generated ctor wins as it's at least as good as the template and it is not a template.

Comment: @Richard, good point there about the conversion sequence. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @Richard: True, but the template still is not a copy constructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt right. which I suppose is why Richard said that my statement was "a bit misleading" rather than "wrong". It was IMO misleading enough that I had to revise it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear from your question, but I suspect what is happening is that the default copy constructor (which does a memberwise copy only) is being used in some places in your code. Remember, not only the code you actually write uses the copy constructor - the compiler uses it too.