# competing implicit and template copy constructors

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, copy, implicit

In relation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249814/templated-copy-constructor-fails-with-specific-templated-type) post, please explain this behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct B { B(B&) { } B() { } };
struct A {
  template<typename T>
  A(T&){ printf("A(T&)\n"); }
  A() { }
//  B b; // when this is uncommented, output changes 
  int i;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  A b(a);

// B b; commented:
// template wins:
//   A<A>(A&)  -- specialization
//   A(A const&); -- implicit copy constructor
// (prefer less qualification)

// B b; uncommented:
// implicit copy constructor wins:
//   A<A>(A&)  -- specialization
//   A(A&); -- implicit copy constructor
// (prefer non-template)

  printf("\nA\n");
  A const a1;
  A b1(a1);

// B b; commented:
// implicit copy constructor wins: 
//   A(A const&) -- specialization
//   A(A const&) -- implicit copy constructor
// (prefer non-template)

// B b; uncommented:
// template wins:
//   A(A const&) -- specialization
// (implicit copy constructor not viable)
}
```

Output changes when B b; is uncommented.

Apparently, the implicit copy constructor changes from `A(A const&)` to `A(A &)` when `B b;` is uncommented. Why? When I change `B(B&){}` to `B(const B&){}` the  copy constructor changes back to `A(A const&)`. Now the compiler is satisfied that the formal parameter of `A()` will be `const`? Does this have anything to do with the standard? (I'm using gcc 4.2.4.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of the implicit copy constructor for class `A` is `A(const A&)` only **if feasible**. When you uncomment the `B b;` line, this copy constructor is not viable because the copy constructor for `B` needs a non-const input parameter.

```
// Illegal implicit copy constructor
A::A(const A& a) :
b(a.b),  // This line would be illegal because a.b is const
i(a.i)
{
}
```

In this case, the implicit copy constructor is also the non-const version: `A(A&);`.

```
// Legal implicit copy constructor
A::A(A& a) :
b(a.b),  // Fine: a.b is now non-const
i(a.i)
{
}
```

This is the reason way uncommenting `B b;` in your class definition changes the implicit copy constructor and, consequently, changes your program behaviour.

EDIT: Not directly related, but for completeness sake: if `B` had no accessible copy constructor (because it is declared `private` or deleted), `A` would not have an implicit copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this behaviour is well-defined by the standard, in 12.8/8:

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class `X` will have the form `X::X(const X &)` if [... conditions where this makes sense ...], otherwise [it] will have the form `X::X(X &)`.

And indeed, if your class `A` has a member `B`, the const form is not possible, and thus the implicitly-declared copy constructor takes the non-const form.

Note that a templated constructor is never a *copy* constructor.