# initialization ignores constructor templates

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initialization

While pursuing some errors, I stumbled upon the following behavior of initialization, which seems odd to me: While initialization checks for existing constructors, there seem to be cases were templates for fitting constructors are ignored. Consider for example the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct A {
 A() {};
 template<class S>
 A(const A<S>& a) {std::cout << "constructor template used for A" << std::endl;};
};

template<class T>
struct B{
 B() {};
 B(const B<int>& b) {std::cout << "constructor used for B" << std::endl;};
};

int main() {
 A<int> a;
 B<int> b;
 A<int> aa = a;
 B<int> bb = b;
 A<double> aaa = a;
}
```

For me, this produces the output

```
constructor used for B
constructor template used for A
```

this means it does not use the constructor in the third line of main. Why not? Is there a reason? Or is my syntax off somewhere? The template seems to work, as it is successfully used in the last line.

I know the example seems overly complicated, but various simplifications made the behavior I wanted to display go away. Also: A template specialization will be used by the initialization and is how I currently prevent this causing errors (where it caused errors in the first place).

I am sorry if my question is off in any way, I am not a programmer, I am not a native speaker and this is my first question, please forgive me.

Comment: Line 3 uses the copy constructor, not the default constructor followed by assignment.

Comment: When asking "why does it do X instead of Y" it helps to tell why you think it should do Y. To many people doing X might be so obvious that they never think about that Y could happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler provides an implicitly declared non-template copy constructor with signature equivalent to

```
A(const A& a);
```

**because** a template constructor is not considered as a user defined copy constructor, i.e. a copy constructor has to be a non-template.

The implicitly declared copy constructor is a better match in the overload resolution than the template version, and is the one that gets called when you copy construct an `A<T>` from an `A<T>`. This can be illustrated with a simple example, with a user defined `A(const A&)`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct A 
{
 A() {};

 A(const A& a) {
   std::cout << "copy constructor used for A" << std::endl;
 }

 template<class S>
 A(const A<S>& a) {
   std::cout << "constructor template used for A" << std::endl;
 }
};

int main()
{
  A<int> ai;
  A<double> ad = ai; /  calls template conversion contructor
  A<int> ai2 = ai;   // calls copy constructor A(const A&);
}
```

Comment: This explanation could apply to any function, but I think it does not go into the heart of this specific case: why does the compiler automatically generate an independent copy constructor that could be generated from the templated constructor.

Comment: Well, it looks like OP disagrees, which is fine for me :)

Comment: @Gorpik you are right, I hadn't explained it. I added a couple of lines to (hopefully) clarify.

Comment: I would still be interested in why they chose not to accept constructors form templates as copy constructors.

Comment: @user2115777 it could be due to the fact that a template function (member or otherwise) does not exist until it is instantiated. So the copy constructor would not exist until used. So the compiler would have no way of knowing there is one, hence it has to provide the implicitly generated one. There are also metaprogramming cases where it is necessary to know if a type has a copy constructor at compile time.

Comment: @juanchopanza In fact, the copy constructor is not implicitly defined until used (§12.8/4). I guess the language designers thought that a class might well have a non-trivial template conversion constructor which did some conversions unnecessary for a copy constructor. But this is just a guess.

Answer (score 4):

Per Paragraph 12.8/7 of the C++11 Standard:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly.

Moreover, per Paragraph 12.8/2:

> A **non-template** constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&,
>   volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters
>   have default arguments (8.3.6).

Therefore, the compiler will generate an implicit copy constructor here that gets invoked during the execution of this line:

```
A<int> aa = a;
```

This explains why you do not see a corresponding output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I am only allowed to accept one answer and another was first, you will have to go without. I'm sorry.

Comment: @user2115777: No problem, but nothing is forcing you to accept the first answer you get, you can change your mind any time :-) However, this is not to say you should accept this one: the one you accepted is correct and fine.

Comment: I tried to accept both... so I know I can change my mind. There still is the question, why it makes sense to not allow templates to be used as copy constructors (see discussion in the accepted Answer). If you happen to know...

Comment: @user2115777: I guess the reason is that it would be impossible for the compiler to know in advance whether your class has a copy constructor or not. In your specific case, your constructor template accepts any template argument, so that's fine, but in general the instantiation of a template may fail for some arguments, and those arguments for which it fails may well be those that, when used, instantiate a copy constructor. The compiler can't do semantic analysis and determine in advance *in the general case* whether a valid substitution exists that generates a copy constructor.

Comment: @user2115777: There might be other (better?) reasons though. I'm just trying to guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is because templated ctor is not a copy ctor. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249848/341065.