# Why isn't this initialization using my (template) constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Why the output is 0003212 ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename X> class C
{
public:
    C() { cout<<"0";}
    template<class T> C(const C<T>& c) { cout<<"1";}
    C(const C<int>& c) { cout<<"2";}
    template<class T> C(const C<T*>& c) { cout<<"3";}
};

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    C<int> c1;          // 0
    C<double> c2;       // 0
    C<int*> c3;         // 0

    C<int> c4(c3);      // 3
    C<int> c5(c1);      // 2
    C<int> c6(c2);      // 1
    C<float> c7(c1);    // 2
    C<double> c8(c2);   // ?

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What is invoked in the last meaning line?

I can suppose that it's some auto-created ctor
but can't figure out which one.

Comment: @H2CO3: Nope, a template constructor can never displace the copy constructor.  And the default copy constructor `C<X>::C(const C<X>&)` is a better match for the `c8` initialization than any of the templates.

Comment: Your 
C<X>::C(const C<X>&)
and my
template<class T> C(const C<T>& c) { cout<<"1";}
are not the same thing?

Comment: No they are not.  I'll add an answer explaining why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several C++ language rules in play here.

1. A template cannot be a copy constructor. (Standard rule 12.8p2)

   > A **non-template** constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, const `X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.
2. If no copy constructor is defined, the compiler generates a default one (if possible). (Standard rule 12.8p7)

   > **If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly.** If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor. Thus, for the class deﬁnition
   >
   > ```
   > struct X {
   >    X(const X&, int);
   > };
   > ```
   >
   > a copy constructor is implicitly-declared. If the user-declared constructor is later defined as `X::X(const X& x, int i =0) { /∗ ... ∗/ }`
   >   then any use of `X`'s copy constructor is ill-formed because of the ambiguity; no diagnostic is required.
3. If a template and non-template are an equally good match for the arguments, the non-template wins. (Standard rule 13.3.3)  The rule is a big hard-to-digest mess, I'll show just the important part:

   > [...] a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function `F2` if [...rules about argument matching...] or, if not that, `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization [...]

From the code you provided, only

```
C<int>::C(const C<int>&)
```

is a user-defined copy-constructor that prints `2`.  All `X` other than `int` don't define a copy-constructor, so the compiler creates one.

See also

- [Templated copy-constructor fails with specific templated type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249814/templated-copy-constructor-fails-with-specific-templated-type)
  and
- [initialization ignores constructor templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115859/initialization-ignores-constructor-templates)

Comment: Your rules sound like true )
I continued to experiment and now understand which of ctors is used.
Rules that you've written explain my case nice, but one small question...
Are they in c++ standratd?

Comment: @user2032538: I've paraphrased the Standard to make it easier to understand, but I can find the actual wording in the Standard.

Comment: This answer is far better than the accepted one... :( Too few upvotes, too much ignorance... :(

Comment: I liked this answer better when my summary of the rules was together :(

Comment: Thanks for your nice detailed explanation.Now I'm trying to understand this mistery: what is the reason that template constructor cannot be copy-constructor. Why was this condition included into c++ standard...

Comment: @Papirosnik: I'm not sure why the language design committee added that rule.  It's easy to go from proposals and rationale to the final rule, but going in reverse is unfortunately a bit harder.

Comment: @Papirosnik: [This discussion](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/ewg/issue32) indicates that tuples need it that way, but doesn't have a complete explanation :(

Comment: @Papirosnik: Another reason is for constructor inheritance / constructor perfect forwarding.  If the forwarding template could be used for a copy constructor, you'd get forwarding to the base copy constructor, but not copying of members in the derived class.  That would be bad.

Comment: @Ben Voigt
I had roughly the same thoughts ).
Some explanations were also found in the link you have provided above (the first one in the See also).

Comment: @Papirosnik: While Johannes always writes good answers, I couldn't find anything in his that really said "why".  Like mine, he described the way things are and the effects, but not the rationale.

Answer (score 4):

It's copy constructor generated for you by compiler, and since it's best match it's selected in last case.

Comment: c6 is of type C<int> and c2 is of type C<double>. These are to completely separate classes as far as compiler is concerned. So to find which ctor to use, compiler needs to consider C<int> ctors (generate list of possible matches). First one is obviously not ok. Second one might work. Third one takes different type (C<int>) from actuall parameter (C<double>) so is not ok. Last one also is not ok, since it takes things of form C<T*> which is not matching C<double>. So there is only one possible match for this case.

Comment: You're right
I managed to see the trails of that generated constructor in asm listing.
and now I understand what happens under hood )
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In last case you call default copy constructor.